# php_mysql is disabled so why am I still getting the mysql_connect() error?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

I am working with IIS. I just upgraded php from 5.2 to 7.0. Unfortunately, I'm getting the WSOD. However, the WSOD happens inside my dashboard area and not on the home page (I'm on a multisite installation, by the way).

I added the necessary lines in my php.ini file to get the errors to show and this is what came up on the white screen:

"Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in E:\inetpub\fcpsblogs\wp\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php:1564

Stack trace:

`#0 E:\inetpub\fcpsblogs\wp\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php(592): wpdb->db_connect()

`#1 E:\inetpub\fcpsblogs\wp\wordpress\wp-includes\load.php(404): wpdb->__construct('[username]', '[password]', 'wp', 'localhost:3307')

`#2 E:\inetpub\fcpsblogs\wp\wordpress\wp-settings.php(106): require_wp_db()

`#3 E:\inetpub\fcpsblogs\wp\wordpress\wp-config.php(124): require_once('E:\inetpub\fcps...')

`#4 E:\inetpub\fcpsblogs\wp\wordpress\wp-load.php(37): require_once('E:\inetpub\fcps...')

`#5 E:\inetpub\fcpsblogs\wp\wordpress\wp-admin\admin.php(31): require_once('E:\inetpub\fcps...')

`#6 E:\inetpub\fcpsblogs\wp\wordpress\wp-admin\index.php(10): require_once('E:\inetpub\fcps...')

`#7 {main} thrown in E:\inetpub\fcpsblogs\wp\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1564"

(all minus the tick marks at the beginning of each line. I added those so that the pound symbol can show)

So I researched the error and it said that WP was thorwing this because I was using php_mysql as opposed to php_mysqli. I searched high and low and I cannot find where php_mysql is. I believe it's disabled everywhere. There's not even a reference to it in my php.ini file. Can anyone tell me where else I can check so that I can get past this issue?

Comment: PHP7 removed all mysql_ functions.  What version Wordpress are you trying to run?  It must be outdated.

Comment: @Devon It was outdated. I'm not up to 4.9.6

Comment: So, there's your answer. Update Wordpress because the version you're running doesn't support PHP 7

Comment: @Devon I have. It's still not working.

Comment: Having same issue here